# How to install Python extension on VS Code 1.36.1

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code 1.36 on a Windows 7 PC and trying to install the Python extension by downloading the .vsix file from the Market Place as I do not have Admin rights on the PC. I have already installed Python 3.8.0 and configures the PATH environment correctly. I then attempted to install the extension from the VS Code UI and also on the command line as code --install-extension , but I get the error "Unable to install extension 'my-python.python' as it is not compatible with VS Code 1.36.1 (the latest Windows version as of today)
On the Market Place site the extension does not specify which VS Code version is compatible.
Can anyone help me understand which python extension I should be installing for this VS Code version. Also could this be due to not having Admin Rights ?
Or is there something I am not doing right ?
Many Thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2019.10 release of the extension requires VS Code 1.38 or newer (as I write this). You have two options that I know of. One is to install a newer version of VS Code using the user installer to avoid requiring admin rights. The other is to go through the [extension releases](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases) and find one that is compatible with VS Code 1.36.